# Complex if and else statement with preg_replace function

Tags: php, if-statement

Good evening...Am a newbie to programming and I was able to work my way round getting url in text to display as link using the codes below

```
<?php 
$textorigen = $row_get_tweets['tweet'];

// URL starting with http://
$reg_exUrl = "/(^|\A|\s)((http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\/\S*)?)/";
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $textorigen, $url)) { 
// make the urls hyper links
$text_result=preg_replace( $reg_exUrl, "$1<a href=\"$2\">$2</a> ", $textorigen );
echo $textorigen=$text_result;

} else {

// if no urls in the text just return the text
 echo $text_result=$textorigen;
}   

// URL starting www.
$reg_exUrl = "/(^|\A|\s)((www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(\/\S*)?)/";
if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text_result, $url)) {

// make the urls hyper links
$text_result=preg_replace( $reg_exUrl, "$1<a href=\"http://$2\">$2</a>", $text_result );
echo $textorigen=$text_result;

 ?>
```

So Its works fine but duplicates my post if its the second if statement found true i.e (www.anything.com) and If there's a post without a link it doesnt display it.Am very sure its my if statement that is wrong and have spent hours trying to fix it..Kindly help me.

I want it to :

1) Display a www link if posted
 2) Display a http link if posted
 3) Display the link if no htto or www is posted..Thanks

Kindly note the preg_replace function works perfectly well

Comment: It is not clear what you intend to do. The title of your question is not descriptive of your actual issue.

Comment: Do you have an example of "$textorigen" it's likely the regX you are using can be improved to accommodate links without the http:// section and thereby simplify the code. For example this (https?\:\/\/|ftps?\:\/\/|www\.) which matches http:// https:// ftp:// ftps:// and www.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix yeah Please how do I add www. to my regX...That would solve the whole problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that every time the program reaches `echo`, the post gets printed again.

So my suggestion is to change all `echo $textorigen=$text_result;` to just `$textorigen=$text_result;`, and at the very end of the all the replacement logic put `echo $textorigen;`.

Comment: Thank you..Have tried that..The post doesn't get duplicated but a post without a url is not being displayed...

Comment: I think there a multiple issues here. I have explained how to resolve the duplication issue.  The other issue probably deserves its own question with your updated code.